# How prove that $\log_3{5} + \log_2{5}$ is irrational?

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, rationality-testing

How prove that: $\log_3{5} + \log_2{5}$ is irrational?

$$\log _3{5} + \log _2{5}=\frac{1}{\log _5{3}}+ \frac{1}{\log _5{2}}= \frac{\log _5\left( 3\cdot 2\right) }{\log _53 \cdot \log _52}$$

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/185540/